# Add French and Arabic Language in my Website

Tags: commerce, i18n-l10n

Can I add multiple languages to my website, such as French and Arabic?

If so, how can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a D7 site, make sure core module **Locale** is enabled.

Navigate to admin/config/regional/language within your site. On that page use the 'Add language' link. Then select a language you want to be added to your site 'the Language name' drop-down, eg 'French'. Use the [Localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module to [enable automatic translation updates](https://www.drupal.org/node/1412862).

Repeat this process for adding more then just 1 language.

Refer to [Install a language](https://www.drupal.org/node/21145) for more details (which also details the steps for D6 and D8).